# Get data of first cell of clicked table row

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" id="newtable">
                <tr>
                    <th>Room No</th>
                    <th>AC</th>
                    <th>Deluxe</th>
                    <th>Tariff</th>
                </tr>
                <c:forEach var="room" items="${myrooms}">
                    <tr bgcolor="#4B476F" onMouseOver="this.bgColor='gold';" onMouseOut="this.bgColor='#4B476F';">

                        <td class="nr"><c:out value="${room.roomno}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${room.ac}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${room.deluxe}" /></td>
                        <td>&#8377;<c:out value="${room.price}" /></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="mybutton" onclick="rowFunction()">Pay</button> </td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
```

On clicking the button corresponding to every row, I want my script to return the Room number i.e. the first cell data of the row. I have tried a lot of things after referring various articles on the Internet. Nothing seems to work. Please help. AND I REQUEST YOU TO POST NO JQUERY SOLUTIONS. ONLY JAVASCRIPT.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the clicked element to your function:

```
<td><button type="button" class="mybutton" onclick="rowFunction(this)">Pay</button> </td>
```

and traverse the DOM:

```
function rowFunction(el) {
   var n = el.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].textContent;
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML5 function `document.querySelectorAll` to get a list of your buttons, then add an event listener to them that will allow you to access their parent row, and get its first cell.

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#newtable tbody .mybutton');

function buttonClicked(e) {
    var button = this,
        cell = button.parentElement,
        row = cell.parentElement,
        firstCell = row.querySelector('td');
    alert(firstCell.innerHTML);
}

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', buttonClicked);
}
```

[Here is the fiddle I used to verify my code](http://jsfiddle.net/bbe2reuw/2/). Also, consider using CSS instead of JavaScript to style your rows' color and hover color. It will be cleaner and more maintainable in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

Use Like

```
$(".mybutton").click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().siblings().eq(0).text());
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/etgg1r8e/)